# How to get only XML in Soap Client output PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am consuming a web service using soap client & its working fine. My Soap Client code is:

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.example.com/erpsync/erp_sync.asmx?WSDL';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$xml_array['userName']  = 'Admin';
$xml_array['password']  = 'admin@123';
$xml_array['ItemNo']    = '4005002335910';

try
{
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
   //$response = $client->GetAllItemData($xml_array);
   $response = $client->GetAllItemStock($xml_array);
   //$response = $client->GetStockByItem($xml_array);

   //echo $client->__getLastRequest();

}

catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error!";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
   echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

var_dump($response);
```

Output looks like this :

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["GetAllItemStockResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["any"]=>
    string(113098) "<ERPitems xmlns=""><ItemData><ItemCode>AG40-01811-I354 .....</ERPitems>"
}
}
```

In the output, i want to eliminate everything before the `<ERPitems xmlns="">` Tag and after the `</ERPitems>` Tag.

How to do it?

Comment: Output only that part of the string? I struggle to see what it has to do with `SOAP` itself (unless you're planning to define a custom class for `GetAllItemStockResult` responses which parses the xml-in-xml (hate those kind of services) automatically for you).

Comment: i am not defining any custom class. I am trying to figure out that from where this data came from (before <ERPitems xmlns=""> tag)

Comment: ... from your `var_dump`, which dumps the object you received... You probably want to do something with `$response->GetAllItemStockResult->any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Preg_match to find pattern

```
$str = '<ERPitems xmlns=""><ItemData><ItemCode>AG40-01811-I354 .....</ERPitems>';

echo getTextBetweenTags($str, "ERPitems");

function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname.*?>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
 }
```

Comment: If it is the answer you are looking for then please mark it answered.